# php backup sqlite3 db issue

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I'm attempting to backup a few sqlite3 databases via a small php script. This script successfully outputs all the files of the correct size into the proper location. The problem arises (And I've only just realized this today when trying to migrate my website to a new location) that these backups do not work.

When I go to import these backups using phpLiteAdmin, I get an error `near "SQLite": syntax error`

If I open this file in notepad++, all the data is there. The file starts with `SQLite format 3` which I believe is causing the issue. But removing this on a copy of this backup does not fix the issue.

I have tried many different ways to backup the databases, all using PHP's `exec()` command to execute sqlite3 code.

Here is my current backup script. This basically loops through all the databases and backs them up into their own folder with a timestamp in a `backups` folder. I am using sqlite3's `.backup` which outputs the file, currently with a .sql extension. I have also tried `.schema` and `.dump` but neither of these output anything.

I am at a complete loss here, I'm lucky I still have the original databases in-tact, but I need to be able to automatically back up these databases to be restored at a later date if needed.

```
    <?
$today = date("m-d-Y");
$time = date("g:iA");

backup("db");
backup("development");
backup("inventory");
backup("permissions");
backup("reports");
backup("rollcall");
backup("upc");

$files = getDirContents('backups');
$start = "/home5/aspiretw/public_html/myticketroll/otherdb/modelfinder/pages/db/";

foreach($files as $value) {
    $value = substr($value, strlen($start));
    @$act = explode("_", $value);
    @$act = explode("/", $act[0]);

    if(strtotime("$act[2] 17:14:40") > strtotime('-7 days')) {
        unlink($value);
    }
}

function backup($db) {

    global $today, $time;

    $dir = "backups/$db/";
    if (!is_dir($dir)) {
        mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
    }

    $path = $dir.$today."_".$db."_".$time.".sql";

    exec("sqlite3 '$db' '.backup '".$path."''");
}

function getDirContents($dir, &$results = array()){
    $files = scandir($dir);

    foreach($files as $key => $value){
        $path = realpath($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value);
        if(!is_dir($path)) {
            $results[] = $path;
        } else if($value != "." && $value != "..") {
            getDirContents($path, $results);
            if(substr($path, -4) == ".bak") {
                $results[] = $path;
            }
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.backup` command simply copies the database file (while correctly handling transaction isolation).

To restore it, simply copy it back.